# Varnish Cache, refresh content for user

Tags: apache, caching, nginx, varnish

Just starting using varnish and was wondering if it was possible to NOT cache certain urls. Issue I've having is I have a few 'promotions' that run for x-y dates. Once the promotion hits 'y' I can purge my varnish cache refresh MY browser and every things fine. But for user who DONT refresh they will still see the old content.

Could I use expires header? Or is there a feature in varnish for this? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cache-control` (and the legacy `Expires` header) can be used if you want to prevent *clients* from caching content after a certain date.  It sounds as if you already know how to purge your Varnish cache, so you should be all set.

[This document](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/) seems to cover the cache headers in some detail.